# Can I eat venison that was frozen for 13 years?

Tags: food-safety, meat, freezing, food-preservation, venison

My mother in law has has vacuum sealed venison in the freezer for about 13 years. Would it still be ok to eat? It doesn't look like anything is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

The US FDA guidelines do not explicitly call out game meat, but none of their guidelines call for storing meat in the freezer for more than one year.

https://www.fda.gov/media/74435/download